# How to get specific field values from XML Response in Java?

Tags: java, xml

When I am printing my API response, which gives me below xml as Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <BugInfo xmlns="ctessng" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <Bug id="CSCvz53137">
    <Field name="Assigned Date">09/01/2021 21:12:25</Field>
    <Field name="Archived">N</Field>
    <Field name="Assigner">James Vilson</Field>
    <Field name="Status">V</Field>
    <Field name="Submitter">Spark Mery</Field>
    <Field name="Reason">Technically Inaccurate</Field>
    <Field name="Regression">Y</Field>
    <Field name="Resolved Date">09/02/2021 02:12:37</Field>
    <Field name="Version">001.010</Field>
   </Bug>
</BugInfo>
```

I want to fetch only specific values form this xml, like Assigned Date, Assigner, Submitter & Resolved-on

```
Assigned Date --> 09/01/2021 21:12:25
Assigner --> James Vilson
Submitter --> Spark Mery
Resolved Date --> 09/02/2021 02:12:37
```

What is the best/simplest way to read in values from this xml?

Comment: What framework/library do you use to send and receive the API request ?
And did you try to solve it in Java already, any [example] you can show?

Comment: I am using OkHttpClient library for API request & tried multiple things like DocumentBuilderFactory & SAXParser

Comment: OK, good start! Then please add some or all of these things you tried as code to your post. Then we have a concrete issue to solve. Such open questions for "best/simplest" are usually closed as [off-topic] and opinionated 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regex

The most versatile would be plain text-filtering (match/find, extract) using a **regular expression**:

`<Field name=\"(Assigned Date|Assigner|Submitter|Resolved Date)\">(.*)<`

Iterating with `find()` then `group(1)` and `group(2)` can give you the desired strings.

See this [regex demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyypkqh6yr)

#### XPath

The pure XML-parsing way would be to use any XML parser, like `DocumentBuilderFactory` and `SAXParser` which can be used to read the XML into a document, then find the desired XML-nodes (`Field` elements) via **XPath expression**:

`/BugInfo/Bug/Field[@name="Assigner"]|//Field[@name="Assigned Date"]|//Field[@name="Submitter"]|//Field[@name="Resolved Date"]`

Iterating over the found nodes we can extract the child as text value.

```java
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.compile(xPathExpression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

See:

- [Filtering XML Document using XPATH in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959791/filtering-xml-document-using-xpath-in-java)
- [XPath OR operator for different nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes)

#### XML mapping

The object-oriented way would use an **XML mapper** like **Jackson** to deserialize (unmarshall) the XML to an object.
Similar to the *OkHTTP* Recipe: [Parse a JSON Response With Moshi (.kt, .java)](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#parse-a-json-response-with-moshi-kt-java)

Then you would need a class where you can map the XML nodes to.

```java
class Bug {
    String submitter;
    String assigner;
    Date assignedOn;
    Date resolvedOn
}
```

The mapping can be a bit tricky here, because from XML-model point-of-view a `Bug` node contains a collection of children `Field`s. But the target type, is *semantically* not a field-list, but a Bug-object with different typed properties.

This is probably the cleanest because it will be easy to parse: `Bug bug = new XmlMapper().readValue(xmlString, Bug.class)`.